# Is it possible to use Google Cloud Anchors between 2 devices?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

I investigated Google ARCore, and I wonder whether it is possible to use Google Cloud Anchors for moving object between two Android devices?

Answer (score 0):

For clarification: do you mean with "moving objects between two devices" that you place an object with one device and see it with the other?
I didn't try the cloud anchors myselfe, but if you are looking for something like: https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/original_images/google_justALine_GIF6_180506a.gif I think it should work.
That gif is from the Google ARCore 1.2 blog post: https://blog.google/products/google-vr/experience-augmented-reality-together-new-updates-arcore/
And also in this video it looks like that you can place an object with one device and see it with the second device https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nSUPJpbTwE

Did you try the unity cloud anchor sample project? See: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/tree/master/Assets/GoogleARCore/Examples/CloudAnchor

Comment: Yes, I tried Google cloud anchors but looks like it doesn't fit for active games (like racing, shooting etc.). Also, I tried to use Unity Network Manager, and it works fine but devices have a differ coordinate system. And for now, my main problem is trying to sync coordinate system between 2 devices. I can't understand how Google Anchors determinate precision place in the space for displaying objects.

Comment: Okay, I didn't have the time to try the Cloud Anchors. But if you are going for the Unity Networkmanager, then I think you should ask a new question about synchronize coordinate systems.